# On subdirect products

Tags: gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, fibered-products

I'm sorry if this question doesn't fit with MO rules, but I've asked on Math SE yet without answers, so I post here with the hope someone will answer me.

I want to show, knowing the [Goursat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma), that given two groups $G, G'$ and a subgroup $H \subset G\times G'$, the projections $p_1: H \rightarrow G $ and $p_2:H \rightarrow G'  $ are surjective (this is the subdirect product) iff $(H,p_1,p_2)$ is a fiber product.

Also: there is a kind of paper or reference or knowledge somewhere which tells about the [Griess notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group#Subgroups) of subdirect product?

Comment: You should explain what you have tried so far (it indeed belongs to StackExchange rather than here). Also please provide the MathSE link.

Comment: As it says on the linked Wikipedia page, this is an immediate consequence of Goursat's Theorem!